# RPi freezes during boot (bind9 samba)

Tags: samba

My Raspberry Pi freezes while booting.

I am using it for local DNS server (**bind9**), NAS, media Library (DLNA, UPNP) etc.

I've lately set up a WiFi Hotspot (Access Point), but today, after i recognised my Raspberry has no internet connection (SSH Refuses to connect), I rebooted it by plugging out the power cable.

Surprisingly I couldn't access the RPi via SSH after the reboot, so i connected my PC Screen and keyboard.

"**Screenshot:**"

[image]

After this line, noting happens. I Can't even cancle it via CTRL + C (keyboard is working)

```
[....] Starting domain name service...: bind9[....] Starting Samba daemons: mbd smbd
```

I didn't back up my files (shame on me), so a hard reset would be the last solution...

Hope you can help me